# Absolute path in python

Tags: python, path, pydev, absolute-path

I'm writing a python project in eclipse with PyDev.
And I'm facing a problem.
Here's construction of project
[image: Here's construction of project]

In a file in breaking_cipher package, I get the absolute path of "english_quadgrams.txt"

```
def __init__(self,filename="./dic/english_quadgrams.txt"):
    self.filename = os.path.abspath(filename)
    #self.filename = filename
    print "self:", self.filename
    self.dic,self.floor = generate_dic(self.filename)
```

The issue is when I import project to use in comandline, it obtained wrong abs dir.
The dir shoudbe be "C:\Users\windy_000\workspace\cipher\dic\english_quadgrams.txt", but
error display "C:\Users\windy_000\workspace\dic\english_quadgrams.txt".
[image: comandline]
Did I do something wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Relative path is relative to the current working directory ([`os.getcwd()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.getcwd)), not relative to the module/package file path.

If you want the path to be relative to the moduel/packages, use `__file__`:

```
def __init__(self, filename="./dic/english_quadgrams.txt"):
    self.filename = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)), filename)
    ....
```